# React SVG Render issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import an SVG file as follows:

`import ExampleIcon from './icons/example.svg';`

But I'm getting a render error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/example.edcd2c8d.svg') is not a valid name.`

How can I use a simple import without needing to cast ExampleIcon as a React Component as follows?

`import { ReactComponent as ExampleIcon } from './icons/example.svg';`

I'm trying to keep my code standardized within the code base, so I would prefer to avoid using the ReactComponent method where possible.

Comment: the first thing that I see is that your filename is something "example.edcd2c8d.svg" in the directory /static/media/example.edcd2c8d.svg and while importing you are just example.svg. Please recheck then update me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I needed to use `react-svg-loader` to achieve the result I want, as React disallows SVG imports otherwise.